# Liquid glucose in marshmallows

Tags: substitutions, food-science, sugar, syrup, glucose-syrup

What does liquid glucose do for a marshmallow?

Has anyone replaced liquid glucose with golden syrup or any other syrup for that matter?

What are the effects of using alternatives for marshmallows?

I see a lot of American recipes have corn syrup as a ready alternative but this is not widely available in the UK.

Comment: Corn syrup is a type of glucose syrup.  See also : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7237/67 , http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12145/67

Comment: The recipe I usually use for marshmallows is this one: http://nothingbutonions.com/2013/09/marshmallows/ - originally from Hugh Fearnley-Whittingstall. I've made it many times and it works really well, and requires neither corn syrup nor liquid glucose.

Comment: I've used invert sugar before(it's usually liquid), and substituted in 1/4 of a recipes' sugar allotment for dark malt syrup, both with great success. My experience is that the liquid sugar is easier to work with than the crystalline version when making marshmallows.  See this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14590/what-is-liquid-glucose

Answer (score 1):

Glucose is used to supersaturate the refined sugar. Without it, the refined sugar would crystallize after some time. We don't want our marshmallow to be like that.